# Convert JRE to JDK centos7

Tags: centos7, java, jvm

Hi,
I am very new to this but I have a centos7 server with a tomcat9 server running some applications. I have only JRE installed on that server based on the command below:

```
[root@ppappih02 ~]# readlink -f $(which java)
/usr/java/jre1.8.0_162/bin/java
[root@ppappih02 ~]# javac
bash: javac: command not found...
Similar command is: 'java'
[root@ppappih02 ~]#
```

What are the steps required to convert the JRE to JDK since I need to monitor the JVM?
Do I need to uninstall JRE and install JDK?

Thanks in advance

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to install `JDK` (and dependent packages). You can't convert `JRE`. You do not need to uninstall `JRE` as they can exist independent. Even you can have installed different version of JDK/JRE` and switch between them.